# Respond to HTTP POST request without Location

Tags: http

After a successful HTTP `POST` request, the client can follow the URI contains inside the response header, named `Location`.

I'm wondering if it would be allowed to not provide this header `Location`, for instance on singleton resource such as:

```
POST /users/42/profile
```

...because after this request, if it was successful (status code `201`), the client already know the location of the created resource and so it would be useless to, once again, redirect it to the current URI.

Does the `Location` response header is optional in this kind of case? Is it possible to not provide it to the HTTP client?

Comment: Redirecting is _always_ optional … [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) however is an often used pattern to avoid duplicate form submissions, if the user reloads the current page in their browser.

Comment: If you're saving something that already has a URI, such as in your `/users/42/profile` example, I'm not sure a `201 Created` is the right response. You're not creating something new, you're saving changes to something that already exists. Wouldn't a `200 OK` (which doesn't expect a `Location` header) be more appropriate?

Comment: @joe-white: I agree. In this example, the user's profile was not already existed inside the DB. In Rails applications, we call this kind of route a singleton because the ID is the name of the resource. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

> 14.30 Location
>
> The Location response-header field is used to redirect the recipient
>   to a location other than the Request-URI for completion of the request
>   or identification of a new resource. For 201 (Created) responses, the
>   Location is that of the new resource which was created by the request.

The newly created resource is typically linked to from the response
payload, with the most relevant URI also being carried in the
Location header field. If the newly created resource's URI is the
same as the Effective Request URI, this information can be omitted
(e.g., in the case of a response to a PUT request)

So you can omit the "Location" header.